# Animación en ng-repeat con "delay" personalizado por cada fila no funciona

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css

**CSS**

```
...
    .repeat-animation.ng-enter-stagger,
    .repeat-animation.ng-leave-stagger,
    .repeat-animation.ng-move-stagger {
      /* Comento estas lineas por que estoy intentando reemplazar
      el valor estatico por los valores del array self.actions[index].DELAY */ 
      //-webkit-transition-delay:0.5s;
      //transition-delay:0.5s;
    }
...
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="battleController as battles">

    <table>
        <tr>
          <td><strong>DELAY</strong></td>
        </tr>

        <tr ng-repeat="b in battles.actions" class="repeat-animation" ng-style="battles.getStyle($index)">
            <td>{{ $index+1 + " " +  b.DELAY }} </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**JS ANGULAR**

```
  app.controller('battleController', ['config','Restangular','$http','$timeout', function(config,Restangular,$http,$timeout) {
        var self = this;
        ...
        self.getStyle = function (index) {
          var delay = self.actions[index].DELAY;
          return { "transition-delay": delay+"s" }
        }
        ...
  }]);
```

Estoy intentando cargar las filas de mi tabla con un efecto de delay que tenga diferentes tiempos que yo defina para cada fila (por ejemplo mi array contendria: "[0.5,2.5,5.0]").

Se me ha ocurrido llamar a la función getStyle que me monte una instrucción de estilo para cada indice y así intentar reemplazar la instrucción css "transition-delay", pero no está funcionando y todas las filas van apareciendo con el mismo intervalo de tiempo.

En las dependencias de mi modulo tengo inyectado el 'ngAnimate'.

¿Por favor alguien podría guiarme con esto? ¡Gracias!

Comment: El valor de las animaciones es arbitrario o puedes tenerlos predefinidos de antemano?

Comment: Mi idea era predefinir los tiempos en función a un campo que obtengo de base de datos unos tardarían más en pintarse y otros menos, gracias por contestar :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí te estas enfrentando a un pequeño problema de antemano, `ngAnimate` usa estilos inline con `transition-delay` para finalizar la fase setup de las animaciones por lo que cualquier cosa que escribas en `ng-style` será sobreescrita. Aquí te dejo una foto del problema

[image: conflicto de estilos]

Lo que significa que la forma correcta de hacer esto es usar staggering animations **usando clases** lo que va a limitar muchísimo tu capacidad para generar estilos dinámicos por lo que no me parece una buena opción.

La alternativa sería usar [animaciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/animation) en lugar de [transiciones](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/transition), esto es aún problemático pero puede resolverse.

Echale un vistazo al ejemplo (tarda unos segundos en salir).

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate'])
  .controller('battleController', function($timeout) {
    var self = this;

    self.actions = [];

    $timeout(function() {
      self.actions = [{
        DELAY: 5.5
      }, {
        DELAY: 7.5
      }, {
        DELAY: 3.0
      }];

      $timeout(function() {
        self.actions = [];
      }, 10000)
    }, 500);
  });
```

```css
.repeat-animation.ng-enter {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.5s linear;
  -moz-animation: fadein 0.5s linear;
  animation: fadein 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running!important;
  -moz-animation-play-state: running!important;
  animation-play-state: running!important;
  opacity: 0;
}
.repeat-animation.ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation: fadeout 0.5s linear;
  -moz-animation: fadeout 0.5s linear;
  animation: fadeout 0.5s linear;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: running!important;
  -moz-animation-play-state: running!important;
  animation-play-state: running!important;
  opacity: 1;
}
@keyframes fadein {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
@keyframes fadeout {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="battleController as battles">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>DELAY</strong>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="b in battles.actions" class="repeat-animation" ng-style="{'animation-delay': b.DELAY + 's'}">
      <td>{{ $index+1 + " " + b.DELAY }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Fíjate que tuve que usar una versión de angular reciente y poner `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` para que la animación no se reseteara.

Creo que el problema más grande que tiene la solución es que la propiedad `animation-play-state` tuve que ponerla en `running` con `!important` para evitar que `ngAnimate` la cambiara (ocurre lo mismo que usando transiciones). Normalmente esto te indica que no debes manipular el proceso de animación a menos que de veras sepas lo que estás haciendo por lo que ten cuidado cuando uses código como este en tus aplicaciones.

Comment: Vaya parece que tiene mas historia de la que imaginaba, gracias por tu claridad al explicar el problema, sólo tengo una pregunta: en el snippet que has puesto la animación aparece con el delay contando desde el inicio, si el menor delay esta en la 3º posición aparece primero, si el siguiente delay menor es el de la 1º posición aparece este y así sucesivamente, si quisiera que este retraso de tiempo fuese secuencialmente, me explico: (el 1º elemento tarde 2.5s en aparecer, el 2º tarde 1.5s despues de aparecer el primero y el 3º tarde 5.5s tras aparecer el segundo), ¿funcionaria este patrón?

Comment: @Radigar Por supuesto que sí. Tendrías que especificarlo acumulando el valor en cada iteración `{'animation-delay': '2.5s'}`, `{'animation-delay': '4s'}` y `{'animation-delay': '9.5s'}`. Recuerda que `ng-repeat` te insertará todos los elementos en el DOM **al mismo tiempo** y el CSS los interpretará inmediatamente. En el caso de la animación de entrada son las clases las que se van modificando y en la de salida cambian las clases y se termina eliminando el elemento luego de la animación.

Comment: Respuesta más que completa, mil gracias, De esta forma he conseguido lo que buscaba.